# Output closest previous closing time in python

Tags: python, date

If I have two inputs: `date` and `closing time` as string.

How do I output the **closest previous date** with the **closing time**.

For example, suppose

```
date1 = '2017-07-20-17-00'
date2 = '2017-07-20-06-00'
```

and closing_time = `15-00`, then the output should be

```
date1 = '2017-07-20-15-00'
date2 = '2017-07-19-15-00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def change_date(initial_date_str, closing_time_str):
    closing_time = datetime.strptime(closing_time_str, '%H-%M')

    initial_date = datetime.strptime(initial_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
    date = initial_date.replace(hour=closing_time.hour, minute=closing_time.minute)

    if date > initial_date:
        date -= timedelta(days=1)

    return date

print(change_date('2017-07-20-17-00', '15-00'))
print(change_date('2017-07-20-06-00', '15-00'))
```